# Is there any way to set up form attribute input tags to get Google Advanced Search to work with no JS

Tags: html, forms, cs50, html-input

I am working on project 0 for Web Programming Python and JavaScript Course in CS50. I am having a problem on google advanced form to return items on the input field. I have tried so far here is my code. but it is redirecting me the same google advanced page. help please.

`<form action="https://www.google.com/advanced_search?as_q=q&as_epq=r&as_oq=s&as_eq=t">`

for all these words `<input type="text" class="input_advanced" name="as_q">`
for exact word or phrase `<input type="text" class="input_advanced" name="as_epq">`
any of these words: `<input type="text" class="input_advanced" name="as_oq">`
none of these words:`<input type="text" class="input_advanced" name="as_eq">`
for the
`<input type="submit" id="Search_button" value="Advanced Search">`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the form action attribute. Compare that to the action attribute on the Google advanced_search page and you will see the mistake.